# Como validar um código de barras padrão EAN 13?

Tags: java, validação

Gostaria de saber como validar um código de barra padrão EAN 13 como este `9788576356127`, este código possui 13 dígitos e os critérios para validação são:

1. *Efetuar o calculo do digito verificador;*
2. *Verificar se o digito verificador atual bate com o resultado do calculo (que neste caso é o digito verificador calculado);*
3. *Verificar se o código de barra possui 13 dígitos;*

Preciso fazer esta validações usando orientação a objeto criando uma classe responsável pela validação que possui apenas um atributo chamado `codigoBarra` e um método chamado `validar()` que retorna uma string dizendo se é um código valido ou inválido, pode haver outros métodos ou atributos também se for necessário. Como posso fazer?

Comment: Esse método de [Validação](http://www.guj.com.br/t/validacao-de-codigo-de-barra-ean/49480) não te serve?

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade utilizei o método deste link porem efetua o calculo errado.

Comment: @Bacco é para faculdade, deve criar uma classe que faz a validação, não se preocupe vou responder pq eu já consegui resolver aqui. Vou editar a pergunta e especificar melhor com detalhes.

Comment: @DenerCarvalho certo. É que como vc colocou na pergunta, fiquei na dúvida em que é que o OO ia ajudar no problema do EAN. Se resolveu, é bom postar, caso alguém mais precise.

Comment: @Bacco tranquilow :) Assim que eu responder vc pode me ajudar melhorando o código ou dando uma resposta se quiser :D.

Comment: @DenerCarvalho como eu não uso Java, acabei nem inventando de responder, mas depois de vc postar, se tiver algo em que eu possa opinar, eu comento. Tou terminando um treco aqui, depois eu dou uma pesquisada no cálculo do EAN.

Comment: @Bacco respondi a pergunta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Achei interessante como a outra resposta de autoria do Dener Carvalho explica em detalhes a resolução do problema.

## Problemas

Entretanto, a implementação que é fornecida está longe do ideal. Algumas razões:

1. **Objeto mutável**: é uma má prática. Você passa o objeto para uma rotina e ela pode simplesmente decidir mudar o código de barras.
2. **Orientação a objetos**: a rotina exige a criação do objeto, mas a computação do resultado é feita totalmente à parte do estado do objeto. O método `validar` poderia ser estático ou mesmo receber uma String e a classe principal nem precisaria existir.
3. **Eficiência**: a rotina realiza várias operações desnecessárias, com destaque para o loop que encontra do dígito verificador.
4. **Tipos inadequados**: o método validar retorna o resultado numa `String`. Enquanto isso possa ser conveniente para fins de exibição, isso é altamente perigoso se colocado dentro de uma aplicação real. No mínimo deveriam ser usadas constantes ou Enums, mas um boolean é mais que suficiente nesse caso. A rotina que imprime na tela ou no console deve ser responsável por gerar o texto adequado, de forma a não misturar as responsabilidades.

## *One bar code to rule them all*

Pensando num modelo de objetos, poderíamos introduzir uma classe abstrata pensando em variações no tipo de código de barras:

```
public abstract class CodigoBarra {

    private final String codigoBarra;
    private final boolean valido;

    protected CodigoBarra(String codigoBarra) {
        if (codigoBarra == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Código não pode ser nulo");
        this.codigoBarra = codigoBarra;
        this.valido = validar(codigoBarra);
    }

    public String getCodigoBarra() {
        return codigoBarra;
    }

    public boolean valido() {
        return valido;
    }

    protected abstract boolean validar(String codigoBarra);

}
```

A ideia é ter uma classe abstrata que possa representar qualquer código de barras.

O estado dessa classe inclui o código de barras em si e uma flag dizendo se o objeto é válido ou não. O método de validação é abstrato e deve ser implementado pelas subclasses.

Note que não é permitido criar um código de barras sem especificar o código, embora or pormenores da validação ficam delegados ao método abstrato.

## Implementação para o EAN13

Em seguida, a implementação para o EAN:

```
public class CodigoBarraEAN13 extends CodigoBarra {

    public CodigoBarraEAN13(String codigoBarra) {
        super(codigoBarra);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean validar(String codigoBarra) {
        if (!codigoBarra.matches("^[0-9]{13}$")) {
            return false;
        }
        int[] numeros = codigoBarra.chars().map(Character::getNumericValue).toArray();
        int somaPares = numeros[1] + numeros[3] + numeros[5] + numeros[7] + numeros[9] + numeros[11];
        int somaImpares = numeros[0] + numeros[2] + numeros[4] + numeros[6] + numeros[8] + numeros[10];
        int resultado = somaImpares + somaPares * 3;
        int digitoVerificador = 10 - resultado % 10;
        return digitoVerificador == numeros[12];
    }

}
```

Note como o algoritmo de validação ficou simples.

O primeiro `if` usa uma expressão regular para verificar se o código de barras possui exatamente 13 caracteres numéricos. Matamos vários coelhinhos com uma paulada só, pois deste ponto em diante podemos assumir várias coisas sobre o conteúdo, como por exemplo as posições do vetor de números que vamos gerar a seguir.

Logo em seguida, um vetor de inteiros com os números da `String` é gerado usando uma técnica bem prática e concisa.

Depois, as somas dos índices pares e ímpares é feita com índices *hard-coded*. Usar loops ou streams é um exemplo de complexidade desnecessária. Só faz parecer que o algoritmo é mais complicado do que realmente é.

O resultado é calculado e o dígito verificador pode ser obtido com uma simples fórmula ao invés de usar um laço.

## Usando

O uso é praticamente o mesmo, vejamos:

```
String codigo = "9788576356127";
CodigoBarra codigoBarra = new CodigoBarraEAN13(codigo);
System.out.println("Número do código de barras: " + codigoBarra.getCodigoBarra());
System.out.println("Código de barras é " + (codigoBarra.valido() ? "válido" : "inválido"));
```

A diferença é que o uso fica mais intuitivo:

- Não precisa passar o objeto para ele mesmo como no outro exemplo (!)
- A validação ocorre somente uma vez na vida do objeto
- Não se corre o risco de mudar o objeto e assim afetar o estado dele posteriormente
- É mais fácil de verificar o estado já que usamos um boolean, não precisa entrar em questões de comparação de Strings incluindo detalhes como maiúsculas e minúsculas
- Podemos facilmente estender as rotinas que usam o `CodigoBarra` para aceitar novos tipos de códigos de barras.

Answer (score 4):

## **Código de Barras EAN13**

O código de barras EAN13 pertence ao Sistema GS1 que é um modelo oficial de padronização dos processos de identificação de produtos e gestão comercial, que existe desde 2006, ele é composto por uma sequencia de 13 dígitos e sua simbologia representa os seguintes itens:

- Identificação do país de origem do produto.
- Nome da empresa fabricante.
- Número de identificação do produto.
- Digito verificador.

Veja uma imagem que ilustra sua simbologia:

[image: Código de Barras EAN13]

## **Calculo**

Um dos requisitos principais para verificar se um código de barra é valido é efetuar o calculo do digito verificador, veja como é feito o calculo:

> Suponhamos que estamos usando o código de barras : 789162731405 e
>   queremos saber qual é o digito final. (Verificador)
>
> Some todos os dígitos das posições ímpares (dígitos 7, 9, 6, 7, 1 e 0):
>   7 + 9 + 6 + 7 + 1 + 0 = 30
>
> Some todos os dígitos das posições pares (dígitos 8, 1, 2, 3, 4 e 5):
>   8 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 23
>
> Multiplique a soma dos dígitos das posições pares por 3, veja: 23 * 3 = 69
>
> Some os dois resultados das etapas anteriores, veja: 30 + 69 = 99
>
> Determine o número que deve ser adicionado ao resultado da soma para
>   se criar um múltiplo de 10, veja: 99 + 1 = 100
>
> Portanto, o dígito verificador é 1.

## **Implementação**

Utilizando a Orientação a Objeto criei a classe `CodigoBarraEAN` responsável pela validação do código de barra, o diagrama de classe abaixo mostra sua estrutura.

Diagrama da classe `CodigoBarraEAN`:

[image: Diagrama de classe]

A classe possui apenas o atributo `codigoBarra`, ele ira receber os 13 dígitos do código de barra. A classe possui dois construtores um construtor vazio e o outro que recebe o código de barra.

**Explicação dos métodos.**

Todos os métodos abaixo são responsáveis pela validação do código de barras, e apenas um método pode ser acessado que é o `validar()`, ele retorna uma string dizendo se o código de barras e valido ou inválido.

- Método `getCodigoBarra()` e `setCodigoBarra()` públicos: provê acesso
  ao atributo `codigoBarra`.
- Método `validar()` público: é o método responsável pela validação do
  código de barras, ele implementa os outros métodos privados e compara o digito verificador com o digito verificador retornado pelo calculo, se ambos forem iguais o código é valido.
- Método `obterNumeroPosicao()` privado: obtém os números da posições
  ímpares ou pares que serão usados no calculo.
- Método `somarNumeros()` privado: soma todos os números de uma lista
  de números de tipo `List<Integer>`.
- Método `removerDigitoVerificador()` privado: remove o ultimo digito
  do código de barras que é o digito verificador.
- Método `obterDigitoVerificador()` privado: obtém o digito verificador
  do código de barras.
- Método `validarEAN()` privado: verifica se o código de barras esta
  dentro do padrão EAN13 contendo os 13 dígitos.
- Método `calcularDigitoVerificador()` privado: calcula e retorna o
  digito verificador do código de barras, para calcular o digito
  verificador é necessário passar somente os 12 dígitos sem o digito
  verificador.

Segue todo o código da classe `CodigoBarraEAN` abaixo:

```
package codigobarraeanverificador;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
/** 
 * @author Dener
 */
public class CodigoBarraEAN{
    private String codigoBarra;

    public CodigoBarraEAN(String codigoBarra){
        this.codigoBarra = codigoBarra;
    }

    public CodigoBarraEAN(){
    }

    public String getCodigoBarra(){
        return codigoBarra;
    }

    public void setCodigoBarra(String codigoBarra){
        this.codigoBarra = codigoBarra;
    }

    //Métodos de verificação e validação do codigo de barras.    
    public String validar(CodigoBarraEAN codigoBarra){
        String valido;

        if (validarEAN(codigoBarra.getCodigoBarra())){
            int digitoVerificador = obterDigitoVerificador(codigoBarra.getCodigoBarra());                                    
            valido = (calcularDigitoVerificador(removerDigitoVerificador(codigoBarra.getCodigoBarra())) == digitoVerificador) ? "OK" : "Inválido";
        }
        else
            valido = "Inválido";

        return valido;
    }

    private List<Integer> obterNumeroPosicao(String codigoBarra, String imparOuPar){        
        List<Integer> numeros = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0, posicao = 1; i < codigoBarra.length() - 1; i++){
            if ((posicao % 2 != 0))                        
                numeros.add(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(codigoBarra.charAt(imparOuPar.equals("impar") ? posicao - 1 : posicao))));

            posicao++;
        }

        return numeros;
    }

    private int somarNumeros(List<Integer> numeros){
        return numeros.stream().reduce(0, Integer::sum);
    }

    private String removerDigitoVerificador(String codigoBarra){
        return codigoBarra.substring(0, codigoBarra.length() -1);
    }

    private int obterDigitoVerificador(String codigoBarra){
        return Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(codigoBarra.charAt(codigoBarra.length() - 1)));
    }

    private boolean validarEAN(String codigoBarra){
        return (codigoBarra.length() == 13);
    }

    private int calcularDigitoVerificador(String codigoBarra){
        int somaPar = somarNumeros(obterNumeroPosicao(codigoBarra, "par")),
            somaImpar = somarNumeros(obterNumeroPosicao(codigoBarra, "impar"));        
        int multiplicaPar = somaPar * 3;        
        int resultado = somaImpar + multiplicaPar;
        int digitoVerificador = 0;
        int auxiliar = 0;        

        while ((resultado % 10) != 0){                        
            digitoVerificador++;
            resultado += digitoVerificador - auxiliar;
            auxiliar = digitoVerificador;
        }

        return digitoVerificador;
    }
}
```

Exemplo de utilização da classe `CodigoBarraEAN`:

```
package codigobarraeanverificador;

import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 * @author Dener
 */
public class CodigoBarraEANVerificador{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Informa o código de barra: ");
        String codigo = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();

        CodigoBarraEAN codigoBarra = new CodigoBarraEAN(codigo);
        System.out.println("Codigo de barra: " + codigoBarra.validar(codigoBarra));
        System.out.println("Numero do codigo de barras: " + codigoBarra.getCodigoBarra());
    }
}
```

Nota:

> A classe atende os requisitos da pergunta, não verifica o país de
>   origem e nem valida o código do produto ou o numero da empresa
>   fabricante.

---

**Fontes**:
Desvendando os mistérios dos códigos de barras:
http://www.revistacliche.com.br/2013/10/desvendando-os-misterios-dos-codigos-de-barras/
EAN-13:
https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAN-13

Answer (score 1):

Não consegui achar um validador de código de barras em java, então fiz um validador de código de barras GS1, onde valida os código de barras GTIN-8, GTIN-12, GTIN-13, GTIN-14, GSIN e SSCC. É uma função simples onde retorna verdadeiro se o código de barras estiver certo.

```
public boolean isValidarCodigoBarraGS1(String codigoBarras){
    boolean apenasNumeros = true;

    // Passa por todos os caracter checando se eh apenas numero
    for (char digito : codigoBarras.toCharArray()) {
        // Checa se eh um numero
        if (!Character.isDigit(digito)) {
            apenasNumeros = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    // Checa se o que foi passado por parametro eh apenas numero
    if (apenasNumeros){
        // Salva o ultimo digito do codigo (digito verificador)
        int digito = Integer.parseInt(""+codigoBarras.charAt(codigoBarras.length() -1));
        // Pega todos os digetos mas sem o digito verificador
        String codigoSemDigitoVerificador = codigoBarras.substring(0, codigoBarras.length() -1);
        // Vareavel para armazenar a soma dos digitos
        int soma = 0;

        // Checa a quantidade de digito
        if ( (codigoBarras.length() == 13) || (codigoBarras.length() == 17) ){

            // Passa por todos os digitos do codigo sem o digito verificador
            for(int i = 0; i < codigoSemDigitoVerificador.length(); i++){
                // Checa se i eh par
                if (( (i+1) % 2) == 0) {
                    // Mutiplica por 3 e depois soma
                    soma += Integer.parseInt(""+codigoSemDigitoVerificador.charAt(i)) * 3;
                } else {
                    // Soma os digitos
                    soma += Integer.parseInt(""+codigoSemDigitoVerificador.charAt(i));
                }
            }
        } else if ( (codigoBarras.length() == 8) || (codigoBarras.length() == 12) || (codigoBarras.length() == 14) || (codigoBarras.length() == 18) ){
            // Passa por todos os digitos do codigo sem o digito verificador
            for(int i = 0; i < codigoSemDigitoVerificador.length(); i++){

                // Checa se i eh par
                if (( (i+1) % 2) == 0) {
                    // Soma os digitos
                    soma += Integer.parseInt(""+codigoSemDigitoVerificador.charAt(i));
                } else {
                    // Mutiplica por 3 e depois soma
                    soma += Integer.parseInt(""+codigoSemDigitoVerificador.charAt(i)) * 3;
                }
            }
        // Retorna falso caso nao seja um codigo de barra do tamanho valido pelo GS1
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        int somaMultipla = soma;

        // Entra no while enquanto a soma nao for multiplo de 10
        while ( (somaMultipla % 10) != 0 ){
            somaMultipla ++;
        }
        // Subtraia soma por um múltiplo de 10 superior mais próximo a ele
        // Depois checa se o resultado da subtracao eh igual ao digito passado por paramento
        return (soma - somaMultipla) == digito;

    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sei que esta é uma pergunta antiga, mas tive um problema parecido recentemente e tive a necessidade de implementar uma solução própria para validação de código de barras (EAN-13 e EAN-8).

Hoje a própria biblioteca Apache Commons [EAN13CheckDigit](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/checkdigit/EAN13CheckDigit.html) oferece um método para o cálculo de dígitos verificadores e validação de códigos de barra.

Porém, observei várias situações onde apenas o calcular dígito verificador e validar que o comprimento do EAN é igual a 13 (ou 8) não realiza uma validação válida. Muitas vezes encontrei códigos de barras inválidos que completavam o número de dígitos necessários com zeros a esquerda e que, por coincidência, geravam dígitos de verificação válidos.

Pela definição do sistema de código de barras, sabe-se também que seus primeiros dígitos indicam o sistema numérico ao qual ele representa. Este número pode especificar o país de fabricação do produto ou até mesmo indicar sua categoria. Nesta situação podemos ter de um a dois zeros a esquerda para indicar um determinado sistema ou país.

Pensando nestas questões, desenvolvi o código apresentado a seguir. A classe EANValidationUtil possui o método isValid que pode receber valores Long ou String. Primeiro o parâmetro de entrada é tratado para evitar possíveis erros. Em seguida, zeros a esquerda são retirados deste valor e o comprimento do código de barras é validado. Por fim, o cálculo do dígito verificador é realizado.

Segue o código proposto:

```
import lombok.experimental.UtilityClass;
import lombok.val;

@UtilityClass
public class EANValidationUtil {

    public static boolean isValid(final String ean) {
        boolean status = false;
        if (!ean.isEmpty()) {
            // Remove nom numeric characters
            String treatedEanStr = ean.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");
            // Remove leading zeros
            String shortenedEanStr = treatedEanStr.replaceFirst("^0+(?!$)", "");
            // Validate length
            if (shortenedEanStr.length() > 7 && shortenedEanStr.length() < 14) {
                int sum = 0;
                val digits = treatedEanStr.split("");
                for (int i = 0; i < (digits.length - 1); i++) {
                    sum += Integer.parseInt(digits[i]) * ((i % 2 == 0) ? 1 : 3);
                }
                int checksumDigit = (10 - (sum % 10)) % 10;
                status = (Integer.parseInt(digits[digits.length - 1]) == checksumDigit);
            }
        }
        return status;
    }

    public static boolean isValid(final Long ean) {
        return isValid(ean.toString());
    }
}
```